# EF Core 3: Configure backing field of navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, ef-core-3.1

Consider the following class. It tries to protect the access to the *_assignedTrays*.

Actually, it works perfectly, since EF automatically links the backing field `_assignedTrays` to the property `AssignedTrays` - by convention ([msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field))

```
    public class Rack
    {
        private List<Tray> _assignedTrays = new List<Tray>();

        private Rack()
        {
        }

        public Rack(string rackId)
        {
            this.Id = rackId;
        }

        public string Id { get; private set; }

        public IReadOnlyList<Tray> AssignedTrays => this._assignedTrays.AsReadOnly();

        public void Assign(params Tray[] trays)
        {
            this._assignedTrays.AddRange(trays);
        }
    }
```

The problem is, that our coding styles forbid the use of underscores in variable names ;-)

According to other code examples ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/data-points-backing-field-and-owned-entity-changes-in-ef-core-3-0)) it should be possible to just rename `_assignedTrays` to `assignedTrays` and just explicitly inform EF about that change in the `OnModelCreating`:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Rack>(e =>
    {
        e.Property(t => t.AssignedTrays).HasField("assignedTrays");
    });
```

But that gives me the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'Rack.AssignedTrays' is of type 'IReadOnlyList<Tray>' which 
is not supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property
using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

What am I missing here? Shouldn't it work?

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do really. The workaround would be to rename the backing field, for example `internalAssignedTrays` and add a comment as to why you can't call it something else so it will pass a code review.

Comment: I could be mapped differently (`Property` method is not for navigation properties), but there is no need to, since EF Core convention [supports your naming style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field#basic-configuration).

Comment: @IvanStoev But the convention doesn't allow for this convention without the underscores.

Comment: @DavidG Oops, the documentation seems to be incomplete, `<camel-cased property name>` (the default C# backing field naming convention) is also supported - probably with highest priority.

Comment: @IvanStoev: You're right. I wondered why the integration tests turned green when not using the `HasField` configuration, but I blamed it on 'incomplete tests'...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation does not reflect the actual rules, because `<camel-cased property name>` (the "standard" C# backing field naming convention) *is* definitely supported, and probably even with highest priority.

But let say your naming convention is not supported. You can still map the backing field, but you can't do that with `Property` fluent API, because by EF Core terminology navigation properties are not "properties", but "navigations". This applies to all fluent, change tracking etc. APIs.

In order to configure navigation, you need to get access to the relationship builder. Then you can use the `PrincipalToDependent` and `DependentToPrrncipal` properties of the associated metadata to access/configure the two ends of the relationship.

Or use directly the metadata APIs (currently there is no dedicated fluent API for that anyway).

For instance:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Rack>()
    .FindNavigation(nameof(Rack.AssignedTrays))
    .SetField("assignedTrays");
```