# In Entity Framework Core, is it possible to use a navigation property combined with backing field?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Take the following entities:

```
public sealed class Employee
{
    private Supervisor supervisor;

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long? SupervisorId { get; set; }

    public Supervisor Supervisor
    {
        get => this.Department?.Supervisor ?? this.supervisor;
        set => this.supervisor = value;
    }

    public long? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Department
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long? SupervisorId { get; set; }
    public Supervisor Supervisor { get; set;}
}
```

And the following `DbContext`:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Supervisor> Supervisor { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Department { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .Property(e => e.Supervisor)
            .HasField("supervisor")
            .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }
}
```

When running the update database command:

```
dotnet tool run dotnet-ef database update
```

The following error is generated:

> The property 'Employee.Supervisor' is of type 'Supervisor' which is not supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

How do I combine both the backing field concept and the navigation property concept? My goal is to allow the application to access `employee.Supervisor` and determine their supervisor if they have a direct report, or if they belong to a department use the department's supervisor instead.

I know I can add a new property to `Employee` named `ComputedSupervisor` with this logic, but I am trying to avoid having to refactor a bunch of code.

Thanks for any tips in advance!

Comment: I am pasting a link that I believe might help you out, give it a try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55977692/the-property-x-is-of-type-y-which-is-not-supported-by-current-database-provider.
If either the link was helpful or not keep me posted.

Comment: Hey @vasilisdmr! Unfortunately, the link you posted does not help. The issue in this case is related to the fact that it is a navigation property with a backing field. Thank you for trying!

Comment: What EF Core version are you targeting?

Comment: @IvanStoev EF Core 3.1.2

Comment: Then it should use the backing field by default. Simply remove the (invalid `Property`) fluent configuration. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60617430/efcore-3-readonly-access-to-private-navigation-field/60618772#60618772

Comment: @IvanStoev I think you are the winner man! If you make an actual answer, I can mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: To add the that, your link was perfect since it shows me how to use a different naming convention all together (which is why I was using the fluent API)

Comment: I can't my friend, because it would be a duplicate. But if you don't mind, we can mark your question as duplicate. What about the link, it is something I've answered today, so it was easy to find :-)

Comment: I don't think this is actually a true duplicate. In other words, while the solution is basically the same, I am not enforcing that my property is truly readonly.

Comment: Now it is. Cheers and happy coding.